# How to make entire Link Label area clickable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: Link Label]

I've been trying to get to make the whole area clickable, in the picture you can see the size of the linklabel, but only text is clickable, I want to make the background of the link label(the whole area) clickable too, is that possible? How can I do that?

I've tried using

```
linklabel.LinkArea = new LinkArea();
```

But it only works for the text that i have. I've checked out StackOverflow Posts such as  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549482/making-entire-linklabel-area-clickable) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691783/text-areas-and-hyperlinks) but i couldn't get something out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a panel, with a mouseclick event on it, after that you can add a label or whatever you want

[Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx43O.png)